# Laravel test without exception, throws exception

Tags: laravel, testing, exception, phpunit

I want to test a missing record in the database using Laravel and PHPUnit.

I have setup my tests and set that the method throws an exception. The test gives an error, because the exception has been thrown.

This is my test:

```php
/** @test */
    public function myTest()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $this->_createMemberRequest(['email_address' => $this->email_address]);
    }
```

The testresults:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) myTest
>
> Exceptions\InvalidEmailException: Email already exists

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help!

Comment: The point of using withoutExceptionHandling to get verbose information on why this problem occurring. So your test is already telling you what is the problem. You need to solve that problem at first, then continue with the test Till you get you appropriate exception which you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` is when you get a funky error and you dont know what to do or the error is not clear enough but if you are trying to test your form validations (`'name' => 'required'`) or something like that when storing a request then you have to remove `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` to get your test passed.